# SharePoint 2013 on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU3) (KB4458871) - 13.0.5216.0 Working fine

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, sql-server-2016

I installed SharePoint 2013 on below SQL Server 2016 Version and its working fine 
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU3) (KB4458871) - 13.0.5216.0 (X64) Sep 13 2018 22:16:01 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0

According to below articles it mentioned SharePoint 2013 not supported to Install in SQL Server 2016

https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2016/11/04/sharepoint-2013-and-sql-server-2016/#:~:text=The%20answer%20here%20is%20clear,edition%20of%20SQL%20Server%202012

My Question is now in my case share point 2013 is working fine may be it stable in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

their could be no issue at all or may be you fall in a situation where you need help from MSFT. at that time you will be out of luck.

When a product is not supported by MSFT that means they never tested it for that combination. So they dont have information what works or break in that combination.

Either you move to SharePoint 2016 if you want to use SQL 2016 or use SQL 2014 for SharePoint 2013 for staying in supported mode.

Answer (score 0):

Since it not supported by MS to run SharePoint 2013 with SQL Server 2016, you’re on your own if “anything” happens.

Now, nothing may happen but MS aren’t willing to back the configuration and will not help you if you do run into problems including fixing the product.